# как добавить поочередно каждый елемент масива в новою строку таблицы mysql

Tags: php, mysql, массивы

из данных, введенных пользователем создаеться массив, и в таблице базы данных надо записать каждый елемент в один и тот же столбец но в новой строке, например:

```
$array_m = (1, 5, 3, 8, 125, 6);
```

надо создать 6 строк где в столбце каждой строки num будет записано следующий елемент.

Comment: @shumik-ua А структура БД какая?

Comment: @IlyaYaremchuk два столбца, заполнять надо тот с названием num

Answer (score 1):

Можно так сделать, с перебором массива:

```
foreach($array_m as $value){
  mysql_query('INSERT INTO table (num) VALUES ('.$value.')');
}
```

Comment: сделал вот так, какраз мой случай, но.. echo $value выводит все как должно, но в базе данных создаеться пустая таблица...

$i = 1;
  $array_m = array();
  while ($i <= $num_of_members) {
   $array_m[$i] = $i;
   $i++;
  }
 
  foreach($array_m as $value){
   echo $value;
    $mysqli -> query('INSERT INTO `mybase`.`lottery_$num` (`num`) VALUES ($value)');
}

Comment: @shumik-ua таблица пустая создается? или запись в таблице? БОльше кода напиши!

Comment: упс.. изменил скобки в query(',,,') на query ("...")  таблица не пустая, но выводит только одну строку с num '1'

Comment: @shumik-ua весь код свой покажи по добавлению записей